# generic method to create webcontrols in asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I want to create a generic method for creating various controls:

For ex:

```
Literal l = CreateControl<Literal>("emails", "ltl", name.Name );
Panel p =   CreateControl<Panel>("emails","pnl", name.Name);
```

I am writing method as below:

```
private T CreateControl<T>(string s1, string s2, string s3 )
    where T : Control 
{
    T control = default(T);

    control.ID = s1 + s2 + s3;

    return T;
}
```

This is giving me so many errors 
1) return T -- T is a type parameter but used like variable

Also I am not many properties to set to the control such as Text, CssClass etc in CreateControl method.

Can somebody advise me how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first problem:

```
private T CreateControl<T>(string s1, string s2, string s3 )
    where T : Control 
{
    T control = default(T);

    control.ID = s1 + s2 + s3;

    return control;
}
```

As to your second, I would advise that you create a class to hold the parameters you wish to set and then pass that class into this method.

---

Your second problem hasn't really been defined, and you parameter naming leaves something to be desired, but something like:

```
public class ControlOptions
{
   public string IDSuffix { get; set; }

   public string ID { get; set; }

   public string IDPrefex { get; set; }

   public string CSSClass { get; set; }

   ... etc ...
}

...

private T CreateControl<T> (ControlOptions options) ...

...

var label = CreateControl<Label>(new ControlOptions () {
    ID = "Test",
    CssClass = "Something"
});
```

Comment: can u give me an example for my 2nd problem plss?

Comment: I would also note, you need to consider how you are going to set those properties that are specific to only a single kind of control.